# Reference for hyperplane arrangements

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, hyperplane-arrangements

I am interested in the hyperplane arrangement in $\mathbb{C}^n$ defined by the polynomial
$$
(x_i-x_j)(x_i+x_j)
$$
for $1<i<j\leq n$.

I vaguely recall that the completion of this arrangement should be a $K(\pi ,1)$-space where $\pi$ should be a braid group of some kind. Where can I look for information on that topic?

Comment: This is the arrangement underlying the braid/Coxeter group of type B. That this is a $K(\pi,1)$ is due to Brieskorn in that case https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/brieskorn8.pdf.

Comment: @Adrien And what is $\pi$ in this situation? And isn't it of type D?

Comment: I also think it's type D.  Type B would also include the coordinate hyperplanes, i.e., the polynomial would have each $x_i$ as a factor.

Comment: Right, type D sorry, this is still handled in Brieskorn paper. $\pi$ is then called the pure braid group of type D. This is the kernel of the natural map from the full braid group of type D to the corresponding Coxeter group, where the former has a presentation obtained from the standard Coxeter presentation of the Coxeter group by removing the torsion relations.  There is quite a lot of literature on those, I'm not sure what exactly you'd like to know.

Comment: @Adrien - the very basics, i.e. the definition of pure braid group of type D (or any other type) and why this is a fundamental group of this arrangement.

Comment: Here is definition of the associated braid group for arbitrary type Coxeter groups: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Tits_group. The pure braid group is by definition the kernel of the canonical homomorphism from the braid group to its Coxeter group. In order to understand why this pure braid group is the fundamental group of the associated Coxeter hyperplane arrangement, it helps if you understand the Type A case first. Do you understand the Type A case?

Comment: @IgorSikora The introduction of this paper sketch the answer to your question and provides references. This is also explained in Brieskorn's paper, in case you read french.

Comment: @SamHopkins I think so. If A type is "classical" braid group, then the complement of associated arrangement is a configuration space of points in $\mathbb{C}$. So $\pi_1$ of this space is a pure braid group. Is that correct?

Comment: @Adrien You probably missed adding a link to the paper :)

Comment: I did :) https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210438 this is definitely not the only paper explaining this, but it does focus on the type D case.

Comment: @IgorSikora: That's correct. The paper Adrien linked to is very nice and explains everything in the case you care about (Type D).

Comment: Thank you very much!